# How to combine lines and numbers

Tags: awk

I have a `txt` file like:

```
Large 0
Large 0 
Large 1
Large 2
Medium 0
Medium 1
Medium 1    
small 1
small 3
```

I want to combine all the different large, medium, and small lines so it outputs something like:

```
Large 3
Medium 2
Small 4
```

I have another problem which is similar, yet the other file is just words, such as:

```
MVCC Cybersecurity
MVCC Cybersecurity
MVCC Cybersecurity
```

I want it to output the combined amount of degrees, so the combined amount of times it says cybersecurity.

```
MVCC 3
```

Answer (score 5):

```
perl -lane '@F == 2 and $h{$F[0]}+=$F[1]}{print "$_ $h{$_}" for keys %h' yourfile
```

Read is: when your lines have exactly 2 fields , then update a hash value with the 2nd field for the key being the 1st key. At the end of it all, just print the key and the corresponding value.

data structure for the hash %h is:

%h = (
...
   LARGE => running_sum,
...
);

## Awk

```
awk '
   NF == 2 { seen[$1] += $2 }
   END{
      for(i in seen)
         print i, seen[i]
   }
' yourfile
```

Comment: Thank you! Yet is there a way to do it with the awk command, that would be preferred as that is what we are learning as of now.

Comment: I have added the `awk` version of the same.

Answer (score 2):

#### Using python's groupby()

A nice job for `python`'s (`itertools`) [groupby()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby). Below two small scripts for both (parts of) your question(s).

Simply copy the code into an empty file, set the path to your textfile and run it by the command:

```
python3 /path/to/script.py
```

#### The first part of your question; getting totals

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter
f = '/path/to/file'
for i, n in groupby([l.split() for l in open(f)], itemgetter(0)):
    print(i, sum([int(n[1]) for n in list(n)]))
```

where `f` is the path to your file, in quotes

output:

```
Large 3
Medium 2
small 4
```

#### The second part of your question, counting lines with similar first column

Is a simple edit to the first one:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter
f = '/path/to/file'
for i, n in groupby([l.split() for l in open(f)], itemgetter(0)):
    print(i, len(list(n)))
```

where f (again) is the path to your file, in quotes.

On a file:

```
MVCC Cybersecurity
MVCC Cybersecurity
MVCC Cybersecurity
Monkey Cybersecurity
Monkey Cybersecurity
```

It gives the output:

```
MVCC 3
Monkey 2
```

#### Note

In your example, the lines are sorted. I assumed therefore we don't need to sort the lines first. If your lines are not sorted, please mention.

#### Explanation

```
[l.split() for l in open(f)]
```

opens file `f`, reads its lines and splits them.

```
groupby([l.split() for l in open(f)], itemgetter(0))
```

subsequently *groups* the lines by their first item, and

```
sum([int(n[1]) for n in list(n)])
```

sums the total of the numbers, in the grouped lines.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at gnu **datamash**:

```
$ datamash -W -g 1 sum 2 < ex.txt
Large   3
Medium  2
small   4
```

- `-W` column separated by whitespaces (def. is tabs)
- `-g 1` group by column 1
- `sum 2`  summing column 2

The second example was not very clear; 
The following just counts the number of occurrences...

```
$ datamash -W -g 1 count 2 < ex2.txt
MVCC 3
```